# Why does my computer lag on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, framerate

On Windows 7, my computer runs beautifully at 60fps. When I upgraded to Windows 10, my fps (in games) dropped to like 10 on Low settings. Why is that? It is not a problem with my specs:

Zotac GeForce GTX 970 Amp! Extreme Core Edition (reference 980)
Intel i7-3820 8 core
16 GB of RAM

Is it a bug?

Comment: I have not noticed the same issues.  Have you done a driver update.  Nvidia released a major update driver update for Windows 10.

Comment: When playing which games?  Using the nVidia driver or DirectX?  what have you done to isolate the problem?  When you ask questions on this board you NEED to include a LOT more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the newest GeForce Drivers for Windows 10 installed.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to [edit] this answer and state the specific driver version that works for you. That way, people coming to this question in the future will have some way of knowing whether they are on the right track or not.

Comment: When upgrading to windows 10 from 7, the currently installed nVidia video driver is replaced with the generic MS "VGA" driver. So "any" driver version.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a day or so. I am fairly sure that windows leaves some of the update stuff to be completed in the background afterwards because my laptop was laggy for ~ a day  after installing but it is now doing quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I had severe lagging issues with Windows 10 as well. Here's what fixed it for me:

1.) Press Ctrl + Shift + Esc to access the Task Manager.

2.) Find the programs that are utilizing the highest processing power. On my laptop (Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 3) Google Chrome and the extensions I downloaded were taking all of my processing power!

3.) Right-click the program/app(s) that is(are) utilizing the highest amount of processing power and hit 'End Task'. I ended the task for Google Chrome and all of my extensions and my laptop stopped having its severe lag.

4.) This is optional, but I uninstalled Google Chrome and haven't had an issue since. I'm not sure if the issue I faced is a result of Google Chrome or Windows 10 though, but for now I'm sticking to Edge and Opera.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

It's because of the GeForce drivers.

Since Windows 10 is new the drivers for it aren't that good so that your PC is lagging.

I have the same issue as you. It is not ideal but everything should be back to normal once they release a few updates for the drivers.

Comment: How does this add to the answer from @mugen2099?  Sounds more like a rant